# Is Master of Chains the only way to wield a spiked chain as a double weapon?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

In DnD 3.5, the only way I have found to use a spiked chain as a double weapon is through the *master of chains* prestige class from the 3rd edition book **Sword and Fist**.

Is there any other way?

Comment: I'll have to poke around, but I seem to remember more one than fighter using it as a double weapon ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not that I know of, no. But you do have some options available:
Cavestalker PrC (Drows of the Underdark) lets you treat a spiked chain as 1 handed. Combine it with Oversized Two Weapon Fighting and you can wield two spiked chains.
You can also use the Light Weapon variant of the spiked chain in DMG (1d4 damage) and you won't need the feat.
If you're just looking for a similar weapon, you could dual-wield [Kusari-gama](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Kusarigama_%283.5e_Equipment%29)s.

Edit: Also, do keep in mind that the ability granted by the Master of Chains effectively removes the reach of the Spiked Chain, while the options I presented here don't.

Comment: The light weapon approach is the one I remember.  It was pretty impressive!

Comment: Could some one point the page of the variant?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anything about this; I'd suggest doing a homebrew method if you do want to give it to multiple classes as a double weapon. My main concern with it is that right now it's pretty powerful (reach, trip, disarm, and finesse?) so you would probably need to trade out one or two of those should a base class get the ability to use it.

Alternatively, provide the ability to attack with it as a double weapon as a feat requiring a certain amount of dexterity and strength and you should be fine.

Comment: If granted in the same way as the MoC, it wouldn't have reach; the PrC specifically states that you treat it as a double weapon *instead* of a reach weapon.

Comment: Just going by physics and logic I could imagine you could use it as a double weapon without benefitting from reach: with reach you're holding it in both hands but having most of the length extend from one side, but as a double weapon you're holding ends in both hands and need enough length both extending from your grip to hit with and going between your hands to let you move both your hands freely.